# How to make an ODBC connection in Android?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, odbc

I am wondering if there is a way to make an ODBC connection to a sql azure database through android. What I am trying to do is make an app that lists farmer info for a coffee company Ex(Name, Cupping, etc). That info is stored on a sql-server database. If it is possible what info would I need in order to make a connection Ex(DNS, username, password). If it is not possible I have another idea to making a connection through an httprequest to a php file that makes a ODBC connection to the database.

**Edits**:

- What data is in the database
- The type of database has been changed
- Tag changed from ms-access to sql-server

Answer (score 0):

It is in general good idea to expose your database to the Internet via a strictly defined service interface. This is much better from a security standpoint and http requests are simpler (more reliable) than persistent tcp/ip connections, when on the phone.

Comment: I have changed what the app does in the question. So what i'm saying is that the info is going to be accessed publicly to start out with. So should I still be worried about security because that is what you seem to be telling me here? Also sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

We (Easysoft) haven't tried it on Android, but in theory a JDBC-ODBC bridge that supports network connections between the client and the server would allow you to do what you want. JDBC on Android to ODBC on a windows machine and then to the MS Access ODBC driver.

Comment: Just a regular JDBC connection will work for me. As in I have found and example on Mcrosoft's site for sql azure which is the db I have been using and the java driver download link. Here is the link to the page http://min.bz/oPpx3. For non-windows users who would like the driver download the compressed file.

Comment: Yep, but the original question was to MS Access, and there isn't a type 3 or 4 MS Access JDBC driver that I am aware of. Hence the suggestion to use a bridge.

Comment: Ya sorry the PC program we had used. Was using Microsoft access as the databases connection to the SQL azure server and parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

I can state that the [Multi-tier JDBC to ODBC Bridge](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-mt/), from [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com), does in fact work on Android..

(I believe only Android 2.3+ supports JDBC though...)

Comment: @Gary M. Biggs JDBC has been supported since api level 1

Answer (score 0):

The [Easysoft JDBC-ODBC Bridge](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/jdbc_odbc_bridge/index.html) works fine on Android 2.1 and above. If anyone wants to give it a try get a trial of the software and email Easysoft Support ( support@easysoft.com ) if you need assistance.

Comment: How secure is it, using this sofware on Android?